# ARIMA Invertibility

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima

Not sure if stackoverflow is the best venue to ask this, but - I'm running a time series analysis and getting the error:

`ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible. You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.`

I'm less interested in getting my code to work and more interested in understanding ***why*** we require invertibility. My understanding is that invertibility is the ability for an MA process to be represented by a converging infinite AR process. Since MA processes use errors that we may or may not actually know, I'm guessing Python converts the MA portion of time series to an AR process - so that it can instead use lag values that we do have access to.

Is my understanding correct? Invertibility is required because Python attempts to convert MA processes to convering AR processes, so that it can solve for the MA coefficients using lags instead of errors?

Comment: Please include the code that triggers the `ValueError`.

Comment: Does this help: [Why do we care if an MA process is invertible?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333802/why-do-we-care-if-an-ma-process-is-invertible)

Comment: @MauritsEvers That link goes into why invertibility isn't important in theory, but doesn't explain why Python requires invertibility.

Comment: No that's not at all what the answer from the link shows! In order for an MA process to be *identifiable* it must be *invertible*. When we fit a specific MA model to data, we must therefore impose invertibility as otherwise the model is not uniquely identifiable. By the way, this requirement is not unique to Python.

Comment: @MauritsEvers ah...thank you! that clarifies things a bit...however I'm not sure what identifiable means. does that mean it has the ability to be modeled by some finite process?

Comment: Hi Christine. Identifiable here means that there is a *unique* set of optimal MA parameters that characterise the MA process. If you wouldn't impose identifiability through invertibility, you could describe the *same* MA process through *different* MA parameters (the afore-mentioned post shows how different MA parameters can have the same autocovariance structure and therefore distribution).